# Django TrigramSimilarity error for searches

Tags: django, similarity

I'm trying to use TrigramSimilarity for my django project to query it for search results but it's giving me an error like this:

**function similarity(text, unknown) does not exist
LINE 1: ... COUNT(*) AS "__count" FROM "blog_blogpost" WHERE SIMILARITY...**

Here is my code

```
    query = request.GET['query']
    if len(query) > 70:
        posts = BlogPost.objects.none()
    else:
        search = BlogPost.objects.annotate(similarity=TrigramSimilarity("body", query),).filter(similarity__gt=0.3).order_by("-similarity")
        paginate_search = Paginator(search, 12)
        page_search = request.GET.get("page")
```

As it says that the function similarity is not defined.


Is there a way to import similarity? As per my knowledge there are no such imports in django.

Comment: This is not Django, this is the database... `TrigramSimilarity` is specific to PostgreSQL. In the database, you need to enable the `pg_trgm` module where the function is defined.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to import similarity?

The error is not raised by Django, or at least not directly. `TrigramSimilarity` maps to the `similarity` function in PostgreSQL.

This function is defined in the `pg_trgm` module, which you need to enable. You do this in the database with:

```
CREATE EXTENSION pg_trgm;
```

It is possible that you will need to install the logic behind it. For Debian-like systems, you do this with:

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-contrib
```

Comment: I'm using the database of neon.tech and I don't see any option to use linux commands on it.

Comment: @Dhiman: can you make raw queries, the `CREATE EXTENSION` is a (raw) PostgreSQL query, if not, then likely these are not supported no.